# PHP MySQL Result Set

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I am definitely stumped on how to arrange a result set.

I have a table which currently contains strictly dates.

```
DATES   
ID  Dates
1   2015-05-26
2   2015-05-27
3   2015-05-28
4   2015-05-29
5   2015-05-30
```

each of those dates are also the name of the table for that day which keeps track which user/agent was present for training.

```
2015-05-26
ID  Attendance
101 Present
201 N/A
301 Present
401 Present
501 Present
```

The end goal for this is to create the following table:

[image]

Now here is what I have accomplished for the table header.

```
$data_date = true;

$list = "SELECT * FROM list ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
$result = mysql_query($list);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($latest)){
    $dates[] = $row['date']; 
}
foreach($dates as $x){
    $data_date .= "<th>$x</th>";
}
```

By simply echoing out the $data_date I am able to display the headers like the following.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>AGT</th>
<?php echo $data_date; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

So far so good. The final step of taking the array and creating new row for each and querying each day from the dates array has me at a loss.

I've been trying for over an hour and cant seem to wrap my head around the array needed to query a new row for each agent.

Any pointers or help would definitely be appreciated.

Comment: You should fix your data structure so you have one table with all the dates.  If you need to, you should have an index on the column or partition the data by it.  For what you need to do, having to resort to dynamic SQL is a bad idea.

Comment: agreed, this is going to be a train wreck

Comment: Its is a train wreck lol, Unable to change the current structure which is why this query is being a pain..

Answer (score 1):

perhaps this is a start. date-math routines can grab 5 day attendance results

consider the following

```
create table agent
(
agentid int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,   -- use AUTO_INCREMENT, whatever
agentname varchar(60)
);

insert agent (agentid,agentname) values (109,'Guy Smiley');
insert agent (agentid,agentname) values (110,'Susie Chapstick');
-- select * from agent

create table class_session
(   -- a session is say Monday to Friday, captures a start date
sessionid int not null PRIMARY KEY, -- the week session #
startdate datetime not null,
location varchar(40) -- etc etc
);

insert class_session (sessionid,startdate,location) values (1001,'10/1/2014','Ritz London');

create table session_signup
(   -- the list of agents who should be present
sessionid int not null, -- the week session #
agentid int not null
);


create table agent_present
(
sessionid int not null, -- the week session #
agentid int NOT NULL,
thedate datetime not null,
thestatus varchar(40) -- present, present but sleeping, etc
);
```

Comment: Thanks Drew, I think you gave me a quick fix to my issue, 
Ill create a new table, loop through the array and insert the ATD Atendance and date based on the name of the table, Will try this out and will report back.. :)